# Why is this MVC route incorrect?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

In my MVC application's RouteConfig I am using this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

routes.MapRoute (
    name: "Dictionary", // Route name
    url: "dictionary/{id}", // URL with parameters
    defaults: new { controller = "Dictionary", action = "details" } // Defaults
);
```

At this time this URL succeeds in returning a page:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/dictionary/details/1
```

Whereas this fails:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/dictionary/1
```

With the exception

> "HTTP 404.The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed..."

When I swap the routing around, like this:

```
routes.MapRoute (
    name: "Dictionary", // Route name
    url: "dictionary/{id}", // URL with parameters
    defaults: new { controller = "Dictionary", action = "details" } // Defaults
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

It both URLs start returning a page.

Why is this?

Thanks in advance.

FYI This question is different to the possible duplicate because of the UrlParameter.Optional and the wild carded routing in the other question. This question is more about which specific ordering is correct and why.

Comment: First match wins when it comes to route mapping. more specific routes need to be mapped before more general routes. so in your first example the first route matches so it does not bother checking any further.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do ASP.NET MVC Routes work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438668/how-do-asp-net-mvc-routes-work)

Comment: Because routes are searched in order. `/dictionary/details/1` matches the `Default` route. `dictionary/1` also matches the `Default` route (it has 2 segments) and it returns the error because there is no action named `1` in  `DictionaryController`

Comment: Thank you everyone. This is what I knew/suspected. FYI the first form of the routing was part of a test question and, apparently, the answer was that the routing would lead to a particular page. My answer of "Throws an error" was deemed incorrect, even though in practice the error is thrown. Nice to be proven right once in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the routes that you add to the route table is important. If you reversed the order, then the Default route always will get called instead of the custom route.

Reference: 
https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs